# Magento manage category page edit error

Tags: magento-1.9, category

I am running Magento 1.9.0.1 version . The issue is with my categories. When I click on a category to edit it, it shows as a new category. When I did an inspect element on my chrome browser, I found out that there is a 403 forbidden message.

http://brandsbay.com/skin/adminhtml/base/default/themeoptions.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (File not found)
    http://brandsbay.com/index.php/admin/catalog_category/edit/key/33951b31670aafc3d81e07e1d9be4f47/?isAjax=true Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
    http://brandsbay.com/skin/adminhtml/base/default/themeoptions.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (File not found)

Comment: make sure you don't have anything weird in your root .htaccess, check your logs (apache/magento), check the permissions on said files.

Comment: Hi Thanks for replying to my post. This issue started happening yesterday. This website was launched back in march 2015. There were no issues until  now .

Comment: So what did you change after/for launch? Did you migrate to another server, user another domain?

Comment: I haven't made any changes ,other than uploading products on a daily basis. I checked the server error logs, but nothing is appearing there also . Will it be an issue related to server firewall?

Comment: themeoptions.css is associated with your custom ma_sahara_fashio15 theme. I don't see any similar errors on the frontend so it could be that the files associated with the theme module to let you customise the theme in admin have been removed or have the wrong permissions. I would contact the theme provider to check your theme is installed correctly. This should however not affect your admin category access.

Comment: The issue has been solved by the hosting company. It was caused by their firewall.