# How to display category details for update?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, category, category-products

[image]

I want to update categories in Magento but the problem is when I click to a sub-category (e.g. Desktop) the details of that category doesn't show up in the "General Infomation" form.

**General Infomation** form -- doesn't display the details of selected category 
[image]

Also, the number of products in other categories displays zero (0) but there's data exist when you collapsed one of the sub-category.

---

I did some research and I found these solutions, but I'm not sure if these are safe:

1. In **System > Index Management:** I didn't do "Reindex Data" action
2. In **System > Configuration > Catalog > Frontend (section):** My Use
   Flat Catalog Category and Use Flat Catalog Product is set to `No`

Should I reindex data and set both flat catalog to `yes`? To solve my problem?

---

This is the error in console log:
`POST https://www.macram.com.au/index.php/administrator/catalog_category/edit/key/a788‌​31fe3d7241461e5a23306dd6d58e/?isAjax=true` 403 (Forbidden)

---

PS: Front-end is working, doesn't have any problem on displaying the data.

The version of magento we're using is 1.9

Comment: have you installed any module related to Catalog ? Can you show a logs here ?

Comment: I'm not sure but I'll figure it out. Okay, i'll provide. @AnilSuthar

Comment: have you applied any Patch OR upgraded magento ?

Comment: @AnilSuthar no, but i see a message says "Magento WordPress Integration extension update available. Update to version 4.2.0.16"

Comment: check `mod_security`, permissions and `.htaccess` if there's some weird thinhs

Comment: I'll check them if I already have an access. Thanks for the help! @AnilSuthar

Comment: I already have an access in the files. But, how I properly check the .htaccess ? and I don't know where to find the mod_security. @AnilSuthar

Answer (score 0):

You need to select the relevant category for see detail

**For exp:**

If you want to see **Desktops** data then click on it.
For product count when you assign product to sub category then it will show product count in only sub category.if you want to show count in parent category then select parent category as well as child.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: That what I did but it doesn't display any details.

Comment: In your screen Shot  there is no any category is selected

Comment: I already explain what you said on my question content. Please review my question content.

Comment: I have reviewed your question, have you checked any error in console ?

Comment: yep but not in the log file. I just used google console log. This what it says `POST https://www.macram.com.au/index.php/administrator/catalog_category/edit/key/a78831fe3d7241461e5a23306dd6d58e/?isAjax=true 403 (Forbidden)`

Comment: Check your user permission and make sure you have all access

Comment: yes i'll provide if I already have an access.

Comment: I already have an access. What should I check? error logs file?

Answer (score 0):

I think something wrong with js scripts on your category admin section. You can use F12 to open developers tools and see console for error.

Your problem is related to the webserver settings probably, you might need to check with your hosting provider or by yourself why your server gives 403 forbidden on ajax call.

Comment: This what `console log` says: `POST https://www.macram.com.au/index.php/administrator/catalog_category/edit/key/a78831fe3d7241461e5a23306dd6d58e/?isAjax=true 403 (Forbidden)`


I need to figure this out w/o reinstalling magento because I think it will create a huge problem because we have lot of data stored.

Comment: I found similar problem here http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/79082/magento-manage-category-page-edit-error

Comment: And I changed my answer.